# how to validate array two dimensional in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

hy.. I have using laravel 4 and my quetion 
how I can validate input array two dimensional
for ex in my view :

```
<input type="text" name="result_test[numeric][]"> 
<input type="text" name="result_test[non_numeric][]">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in controller :
$this->validate([
  'result_test.numeric' => 'validation|rules'
]);

same in request 

$rules = [
  'result_test.numeric' => 'validation|rules'
]
```

not shure about laravel 4 , but in laravel 5 + it works like this